# blueimp jQuery file upload plugin hide uploaded files

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I am using this:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Everything works great and all but I want to know how to make it so whenever I have done uploading stuff in it, and when I go to that uploading page again, I want to hide the uploaded files list. Because currently whenever ANYONE goes to the upload page, it displays ALL the uploaded files and ANYONE can delete the files. I want it to NOT display the uploaded files. THANKS A LOT FOR HELPING IN ADVANCE!

EDIT:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin Demo 9.1.0
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Force latest IE rendering engine or ChromeFrame if installed -->
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<![endif]-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Demo</title>
<meta name="description" content="File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&amp;drop support, progress bars, validation and preview images, audio and video for jQuery. Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads and client-side image resizing. Works with any server-side platform (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Generic page styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!-- blueimp Gallery styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
<!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
<!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-noscript.css"></noscript>
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css"></noscript>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload">jQuery File Upload</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tags">Download</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload">Source Code</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki">Documentation</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://blueimp.net">&copy; Sebastian Tschan</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h1>jQuery File Upload Demo</h1>
    <h2 class="lead">Basic Plus UI version</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="basic.html">Basic</a></li>
        <li><a href="basic-plus.html">Basic Plus</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Basic Plus UI</a></li>
        <li><a href="angularjs.html">AngularJS</a></li>
        <li><a href="jquery-ui.html">jQuery UI</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <blockquote>
        <p>File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&amp;drop support, progress bars, validation and preview images, audio and video for jQuery.<br>
        Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads and client-side image resizing.<br>
        Works with any server-side platform (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.</p>
    </blockquote>
    <br>
    <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
        <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                <!-- The global file processing state -->
                <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress state -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Demo Notes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li>The maximum file size for uploads in this demo is <strong>5 MB</strong> (default file size is unlimited).</li>
                <li>Only image files (<strong>JPG, GIF, PNG</strong>) are allowed in this demo (by default there is no file type restriction).</li>
                <li>Uploaded files will be deleted automatically after <strong>5 minutes</strong> (demo setting).</li>
                <li>You can <strong>drag &amp; drop</strong> files from your desktop on this webpage (see <a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Browser-support">Browser support</a>).</li>
                <li>Please refer to the <a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload">project website</a> and <a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki">documentation</a> for more information.</li>
                <li>Built with the <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap</a> CSS framework and Icons from <a href="http://glyphicons.com/">Glyphicons</a>.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- The blueimp Gallery widget -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-filter=":even">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">â€¹</a>
    <a class="next">â€º</a>
    <a class="close">Ã—</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">
                {% if (file.url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                {% } %}
            </p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
            {% } else { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- blueimp Gallery script -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload audio preview plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload video preview plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-video.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<!-- The main application script -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE 8 and IE 9 -->
<!--[if (gte IE 8)&(lt IE 10)]>
<script src="js/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Add code to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `template-download` section to something more like this:

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
<tr class="template-download fade">
    <td>
        <span class="preview">
            {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
            {% } %}
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="name">
            {% if (file.url) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
            {% } else { %}
                <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
            {% } %}
        </p>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
        {% } %}
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

For security reasons, if you don't want to allow downloads at all, you should also delete or comment out the server-side code that performs the delete.

If you don't want the files displayed at all, in `js\main.js` you should also remove the section of code commented as `// Load existing files` because that is the code that requests to download the existing files from the server and display them.